# Generate values with runif and a probability density function

Tags: rejection-sampling

I'm trying to use the rejection method (accept/reject) to simulate samples of various dimensions from the distribution with density function of probability
[image]

And graphically check whether the sample comes from a population with Beta distribution (1/2, 3).

Here's what I've done:

```
 # 1. Define sample size
nvals <- 5000


# 2. Rejection sampling method 
reject.beta <- function(nvals)
{
  x.aceite <- NULL
  u.aceite <- NULL
  nx <- 0
  x.rejected <- NULL
  u.rejected <- NULL
  nrejected <- 0
  while(nx < nvals) {
    Y <- runif(1,0,1) #I can't use uniform distribution
    U <- runif(1,0,1.875) #1.875 = 30/16
    if(U <= (15/16)*(Y^(-1/2))*(1-Y)^2) {
      nx <- nx + 1
      x.aceite[nx] <- Y
      u.aceite[nx] <- U
    } else {
      nrejected <- nrejected + 1
      x.rejected[nrejected] <- Y
      u.rejected[nrejected] <- U
    }
  }
  
  plot(x.aceite,u.aceite,pch=20,col="green",xlab="x",ylab="f(x)",main="Beta(1/2,3) - pontos escolhidos pelo Método de Rejeição")
  lines(x.rejected,u.rejected,pch=20,col="red",type="p")
  x.aceite
}

XX <- reject.beta(nvals)
hist(XX,breaks=20,prob=TRUE,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,3),main="Distribuição(2,3) obtida pelo Método de Rejeição")
x.val <- seq(0,4,0.001)
lines(x.val, dbeta(x.val, 1/2, 3) ,col="blue")
```

However, I can't use uniform distribution to solve this, I need to use the probability density function:

[image]

The suggestion I've got was to assign Y variable with a value from this p.d.f using the inversion method. (I thought extracting a value between the min and max would suffice)

Can someone please tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a cumulative density function $F$ and you want to sample a random variable $Y$ whose distribution functions is $F$ ($Y \sim F$).

To do this note that $F(Y)$ is uniformly distributed. Let $U \sim Uni[0,1]$ then you know that $F^{-1}(U) \sim Y$. This means that all you have to do to sample from $Y$ is to generate a sample $u$  from $U$ and compute $F^{-1}(u)$.

To find $F^{-1}(u)$ in R you might find the function [uniroot](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjfq4ehr_zQAhWGEJAKHcXBDckQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstat.ethz.ch%2FR-manual%2FR-devel%2Flibrary%2Fstats%2Fhtml%2Funiroot.html&usg=AFQjCNFytCy3dvxk9ryveZGw9Uof2IXG2Q&sig2=oTnoc5UW2FlTRr-D4-xCgw&cad=rjt) very useful, since all you really want is a solution for the equation $F(x) = u$.

Comment: Too bad I'm not that good at statistics to understand what you're saying. +1 though

Comment: Can you provide an R example? I'm having trouble in understanding what you're saying

Comment: Sorry, I cant provide a R example, but I will gladly answer any question you have. If you are having trouble understanding what I wrote and can't formulate a question I encourage you to check the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) about the Rejection Sampling algorithm.